# Como ler até o final do arquivo com JavaScript - Uri Online Judge

Tags: javascript

Em `javascript` estou utilizando a plataforma uri online judge, porém, não encontrei nada sobre ler até o EOF (End of File) em javascript.

Alguém poderia me dizer como ler até o EOF com javascript?

Comment: O código de exemplo que eles colocam na plataforma (em node) já trás as linhas todas, e você poder ir lendo linha a linha fazendo `while(lines.length > 0){ let line = lines.shift();` ou até com `for (let line of lines){`. Agora desde já lhe digo que alguns dos exercícios de lá tem problemas nos inputs que fazem com que o código falhe, mesmo sem estar errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando você seleciona JavaScript, já aparecerá para você o trecho:

```
var input = require('fs').readFileSync('/dev/stdin', 'utf8');
var lines = input.split('\n');

/**
 * Escreva a sua solução aqui
 * Code your solution here
 * Escriba su solución aquí
 */
```

Que lê todo o conteúdo da entrada, até o `EOF` e dividirá por linhas. Você não precisará se preocupar com isso.